# Refer to values of other arguments in function call?

Tags: r

Consider the code snippet:

```
a <- rnorm(100)
b <- rnorm(100)
plot(x=a,y=b,xlim=range(c(a,b)),ylim=range(c(a,b)))
```

Is there any way to accomplish the same without saving the values of a and b as separate variables? I.e. something that looks like

```
plot(rnorm(100),rnorm(100),xlim=?MAGIC?(range(c(x,y))),ylim=?MAGIC?(xlim))
```

where `?MAGIC?` is the code that solves all my problems.

I looked into `eval`&co, but they seem to be doing the opposite of what I need... Is this impossible, because it would require referring to a scope that doesn't exist yet?

(The above example is just to illustrate the point, there are other contexts where I've wanted to do something like that)

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you want to save the values `a` and `b`? You can easily remove them at the end of the script/process.  Probably easier than magic.

Comment: @Richard True, saving isn't a whole lot of trouble (I'm rarely worried about memory, so removing isn't really an issue). The main reason this would be nice is that it would make it easier to rapidly produce "hacky" results. Being a PhD student working mostly on theory, the vast majority of the R code I write is composed of small snippets to test rapidly changing things. Every extra line of code gets in the way of that. It's just a matter of minor convenience, really.

Comment: Well, again, if your work consists in *testing rapidly changing things*, the right approach is to turn your code into functions where these *changing things* are your arguments. Then there is absolutely no code to rewrite, just call the function with different inputs and compare the results.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can. Just define a new function:

```
same.lim.plot <- function(x, y, ...) {
    xy.lim <- range(c(x,y))
    plot(x, y, xlim = xy.lim, ylim = xy.lim, ...)
}
same.lim.plot(rnorm(100), rnorm(100))
```

Comment: Well, you *can* do `plot(x=a, y=b, xlim = xx <- range(c(a,b)), ylim=xx)`, but that has the ugly ugly side effect of assigning `xx` into the calling environment.

Comment: but still, that would not meet the `?MAGIC?` format the OP was expecting.

Comment: And no, the OP does not want `a` and `b` variables. You probably mean `plot(x <- rnorm(100), y <- rnorm(100)), xlim = range(c(x, y)), ylim = range(c(x, y)))`, ugly indeed. OP, please don't do that.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It's sort of a moot point anyway, since constructing a simple function is the real answer!

Comment: Actually, I think that's fine for my purposes (not to mention a very simple solution I should have thought of...). Thanks! (As for the ugliness -- I'm not writing production quality code anyway :) )